# Allow only One view that has ablility to scroll the CoordinatorLayout . eg.like Handle view work in Sliding panel

Tags: android, scroll, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have search a lot but not found same question on stack-overflow

**Problem -** I just want that only one view that scroll CoordinatorLayout similar 
like handle view work in Sliding Panel layout

but in my current layout i have two views one is handle view (Textview with text "Route Plan") and other is RecyclerView **What I want is** *when user click and drag on handle view  CoordinatorLayout  should scroll but when user click on RecyclerView it should not scroll CoordinatorLayout it shoud scroll only RecyclerView items*    **is it possible**

here is my current layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sub_tab"
    android:padding="5pt"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
    ​

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/materialup.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        ​

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tvRoutePlan"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="top">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        ​
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    ​


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"><!--com.indus.corelib.ui.FixedScrollingViewBehavior -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRoutePlan"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/map_list_title_gradient"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="5pt"
                    android:text="Route Plan"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@android:id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="true"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Note :-** *when i used other view insted of  RecyclerView than it work perfectly as i want like when i click and drag that view CoordinatorLayout  not move*   but i need recycler view there to show list :(

Comment: You put the recycleview inside the linearlayout that has scroll behavior probably is that you problem try put outsider if you want i will explain better using an answer

Comment: yes please explain it with some xml code ...thanks :)

Comment: I added an answer with two possible ways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup , I got the answer by myself

Just stop scroll of RecyclerView and it just work what i want

```
                 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@android:id/list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
                        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                        android:overScrollMode="never"
                        android:fadeScrollbars="false"/>
```

also i used in java file

```
        mListView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mListView.setOverScrollMode(ListView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        mListView.stopScroll();
```

**mListView.stopScroll()** This is real game changer 
But i am not happy that no one try to solve my prob except  Bruno Ferreira :(  Thanks Bruno for help

Answer (score 1):

So try do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sub_tab"
    android:padding="5pt"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
    ​

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/materialup.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        ​

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tvRoutePlan"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="top">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        ​
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    ​


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"><!--com.indus.corelib.ui.FixedScrollingViewBehavior -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvRoutePlan"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/map_list_title_gradient"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="5pt"
                    android:text="Route Plan"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>    

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@android:id/list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="true"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
            </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So remove **recycleview** from your **layout behavior parent**. Because the **recycleview** isnt inside the **layout behavior parent** he dont do the **scroll** flag. If this not Works the oter way is put the `CoordinatorLayout` inside other layout like a `LinearLayout` and recycleview outside `CoordinatorLayout` but inside `LinearLayout`.

**Note:** It's my idea i don't know if it Works.

Comment: Not work  !! I want the recycleview  below handle view so that moving handle view move Coordinator Layout according to that    ....... thanks for help appreciated

Comment: And if you put recycleview inside nestedscrollview and set android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" in recycleview?